# Excel Object SaveAs, error happens when Existing File is Open

Tags: excel, ms-office, ole, powerbuilder

```
Excel_Obj = CREATE OleObject

Excel_Obj.ConnectToNewObject( 'excel.application' )
Excel_Obj.Workbooks.Add
Excel_Obj.Application.ActiveWorkbook.WorkSheets.Add

Excel_Sheet = Excel_Obj.Application.ActiveWorkbook.WorkSheets[1]

//EXAMPLE

Excel_Sheet.Cells[1,1] =  45

Excel_Obj.Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(ls_file,56)  //csv

//where ls_file = the Opened File
```

error happened after / during saveas.
try catch throw "error calling external object..in click..line.. saveas.."

--
i want to state to the user that the excel file is open therefore cannot be overwritten properly. I used a try catch and throwed a proper message but before the messagebox for the catch event happens, the PB execution error R0035 happens. any solutions or proper way to know if the excel file is open.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to check if the file is open first, have a look at this answer:

[how to check if file is opened in excel using OLE (leaves excel process open)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7176390/how-to-check-if-file-is-opened-in-excel-using-ole-leaves-excel-process-open)

Comment: i could do those using try catch in Powerbuilder. the true problem relies on the PB Execution Error upon knowing the file is open. not before. i also put it inside try, but the error still popped out. i dont think my users will ignore this,lol

Comment: i still need some help on this. I havent figured this out. my users want a perfect excel extract system. Thanks for the answers...!

Answer (score 0):

I'd try a PowerScript `FileOpen ()` call with a LockReadWrite! parameter to see if it can be opened, followed immediately by a `FileClose ()` if it was successful. (I think this is a PowerScript-specific variation on the DXL solution Colin linked to.)

Good luck,

Terry

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried approaches similar to these?

Using Win32 API: 
http://www.rgagnon.com/pbdetails/pb-0030.html

Using PB function fileopen()with the (default) exclusive rights set: 
http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1610670

In other words, see if the file can be opened exclusively before connecting to Excel or making the CSV?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to turn off the option to break into the debugger for that exception to see the exception handling work in the IDE. Look for the Help topic "Exception Settings dialog box" for details. Once you see it's working I recommend you set it back to break into the debugger, since you'd normally want to see what threw the error.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use ole when document is open( even you set lock write) by the user and not by apllication.
my approach, I have been using many times till now:

1. Check excel is open or not, use use can use **api** or **wsh** script in the internet to check app opened. If opened do not run save as and tell user to close excel and not run it for while for while.
2. if you user run excel and your program still running active workbook and worksheet application will be switch to excel that opened by user ( imagine it wrong written data).
3. Change your code as below

   if Excel_Obj.ConnectToNewObject( 'excel.application' ) <>  0 then 
   messagebox("warning", "could connect to excel", stopsign!)
   RETURN 
   end if
4. just for knowledge another technique is DDE call, but not common today and most complicated.

Happy coding From pb developer.